# Facebook comments plugin -- how to override the WordPress theme's color

Tags: css, wordpress, facebook-javascript-sdk

I installed the Facebook comments plug-in on a WordPress website but the theme's color is overriding the chosen dark background color for the plugin.

It's all white but it should have a dark border. I've tried adding `!important` to the plugin's div background color to no avail.

How can I override this?

Answer (score 1):

You can style `.fb-comments`

```
.fb-comments {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because it uses an iframe to load the data. Your best bet may be to use javascript to select the element class and then modify the css. In jQuery, I would do:

```
$('.classname').css()
```